# Magento - Get variable from grid to admin controller

Tags: variables, magento

My question is about,

how to get a variable from a Magemto grid to My admin controller page.
(ie Exactly to my public function `massStatusAction()`)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those ID like this

```
$productIds = (array)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
```

Where `product` is set as Mass Action field in the Grid's protected function `_prepareMassaction()` like this.

```
$this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id')
```

Hope this helps!